# preg_match doesn't work with data from a database

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to get the paragraph that mentions "gimlet" in the text below. And this following code works.

[image: this works]

I have a database, where $result['text'] contains exactly the same text as you see in the screenshot.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM updates WHERE text LIKE '%gimlet%'");
$stmt->execute(array());
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($results as $result) { 
  $re = '/[\*].*(gimlet)(.+?\n\n)/';
  $str = $result['text'];
  preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
  var_dump($matches);
}
```

...and this never gives any result. Anything. Yet, the contents of $result['text'] looks like this:

[image: database]

I don't understand why it works if it is given the text, but if it grabs the text from the database - which is identical, it seems to me - it isn't working? How have I messed up here? It must be obvious, but I can't understand for the life of me.

Comment: Probably have a bad SQL request, this text isn't there.

Comment: I've never seen `$stmt->execute(array());` , that might be throwing an error use `$stmt->execute();`, or are you actually binding? You could do `WHERE text LIKE ?` then  `$stmt->execute(array('%gimlet%'));'`

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the SQL query (which I've edited slightly for the above example and probably messed up). If I echo out the text in the loop, it's there, and view-source looks identical.

Comment: Something must be different. Please provide the output, if we can't reproduce the issue we can't help. Currently we only have an image, please post actual text. (Unrelated but the `*` in the character class won't need to be escaped)

Comment: Someone from Twitter says: 

_Are you sure the database text has \n\n between paragraphs and not \r\n\r\n (which is more common & looks the same)?_

So if I try a regex of `/[\* ].*(gimlet)(.)/` it still doesn't return a thing...

Comment: What is written in the images you posted?

Comment: As others have mentioned, post your actual text. Your regex does look funky. You likely want to use `.+` (you don't need to specify the end of the line as `\n\n` since `.+` matches any character **except** newline characters). Also, you don't need to combine `\*` with `[]`. Use one or the other (just use `\*`). Basically, try this regex `/\*.*(gimlet)(.+)/`

Comment: I appreciate the image is an issue, but I couldn't post the actual text, which includes Markdown without it actually converting.

Here it is as a gist - https://gist.github.com/jamescridland/0775ebd602bfac3b4afc5d609246922e

This works: so the regex is working.

Comment: @ctwheels Well, sir, your suggestion works. You are a star. Very strange. Thank you.

Comment: If it is code then format it as code (hint: use the `{}` button in the editor toolbar). [so] will handle it properly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why, but the following regex works perfectly on both examples. Thank you to @ctwheels who gave me the answer.

```
$re = '/\*.*(gimlet)(.+)/';
```

Comment: You're welcome. The reason is likely because it couldn't match two `\n` immediately following one another. It's possible it's `\r\n` or something else. If you copy/paste it into Notepad++ and turn on the end of line characters (see [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/409919/cr-and-lf-characters-shown-at-the-end-of-each-line-in-notepad) on how), you can determine what characters are actually there.